# Facebook style uploaded image resizing and compressing

Tags: javascript, c#, php, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Facebook resizes our uploaded images if it is upper to `2 megapixels`. Such as my image is `3264x1832`, facebook resize to `2048x1529` it. So which edge if it is long, the images reduces to until the edge is `2048px`. The reducing is measured that the other edge is reducing to. After that the image compressing for the image size is smaller. The method is careful in large images. I will be doing the method my mvc 5 project, how to find a c#, jquery, javascrip, php plugin or api like this method?

Answer (score 1):

This requires GD be installed on your php server, and expects that `path/to/temp/image.jpg` is the location of the uploaded image.  You may want to use `try/catch` in case an unsupported file type or corrupted image gets uploaded.

Here is the main program code:

```
$maxWidth = 2048;
$maxHeight = 2048;
$compression = 75;

//Create an image object out of the uploaded file
$sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('path/to/temp/image.jpg'); 

//Resize the image
$resizedImage = ImageSizeDown($sourceImage, $maxWidth, $maxHeight);

//Save the image as a jpeg to it's new home
imagejpeg($resizedImage, 'path/to/permanent/image.jpg', $compression);
```

These are additional necessary functions:

```
//Function for resizing an image if it's larger than a certain resolution
function ImageSizeDown($image, $maxWidth, $maxHeight) {
    $maxAspect = $maxWidth / $maxHeight;
    $sourceWidth = imagesx($image);
    $sourceHeight = imagesy($image);
    $sourceAspect = $sourceWidth / $sourceHeight;
    if($sourceWidth > $maxWidth || $sourceHeight > $maxHeight) {
        if($maxAspect > $sourceAspect) {
            $newWidth = (int)$maxWidth;
            $newHeight = (int)($maxWidth / $sourceWidth * $sourceHeight);
        }
        else { 
            $newHeight = (int)$maxHeight;
            $newWidth = (int)($maxHeight / $sourceHeight * $sourceWidth);
        }
        $result = TransparentImage($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagesavealpha($image, true);
        imagealphablending($image, false);
        imagecopyresampled($result, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);
        return $result;
    }
    else return $image; //Image is already small enough
}

//Handy function for creating a base for most any image stuff, especially PNG
function TransparentImage($x, $y) { 
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    imagealphablending($image, false);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 200, 200, 200, 127);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);
    return $image;
}
```

I'm not anywhere where I can test this at the moment, so my aspect ratio math may be transposed.